# jQuery exclude element by data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
    <li data-value="-">-</li>
    <li data-value="145">145</li>
    <li data-value="170">170</li>
    <li data-value="300">300</li>
</ul>
<ul class="chosen-results">
    <li data-value="-">-</li>
    <li data-value="0">No</li>
    <li data-value="1">Yes</li>
</ul>
```

I need to hide all element with data-value that match to an array of values.
I've already tried:

```
var array = ['145', '0', '300'];
var $li = $('.chosen-results li').filter(function(i) {
    return $(this).data('value') != array[i];
});
```

but *$li* contain all <*li*> element!

Comment: have you tried `return array.indexOf($(this).data('value'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Array.prototype.indexOf()` at this context,

```
var array = ['145', '0', '300'];
var $li = $('.chosen-results li').filter(function(i) {
console.log( typeof $(this).data('value'));
    return array.indexOf($(this).data('value') + "") > -1;
}).hide();
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k1mmtbop/)

Comment: It works perfectly, many thanks! :) Even if I don't understand the meaning!

Answer (score 0):

This works - create an array of the elements you wish to hide then iterate through it and using a regex filter, if the element matches then hide it. Note that this can work in the reverse as well - simply hide all li's at the top of the function and then swap the .hide() to .show() to display the matching elements. Only thing - I had to make the yes / no values as "00" and "01" to ensure that they are unique and didn't just match "0" and "1".

```js
 $(function() 
 {  
 
  var list=["145","300","00"];
  
  $('.chosen-results li').each(function(){
  for (i=0;i<list.length;i++)
   {
    var rex = new RegExp(list[i], 'i');
    $('.chosen-results li').filter(function() {
      return rex.test($(this).attr('data-value'));
       }).hide();
   }
  })
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> 
    <title>List Filter</title>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="chosen-results">
    <li data-value="-">-</li>
    <li data-value="145">145</li>
    <li data-value="170">170</li>
    <li data-value="300">300</li>
</ul>
<ul class="chosen-results">
    <li data-value="-">-</li>
    <li data-value="00">No</li>
    <li data-value="01">Yes</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```